# can't insert in database mysql

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I cannot insert it to my database mysql but I think I already did it the right way. is there anyone know how to solve it? or I missed something?. it actually all work. but it won't take the value from body that I put in postman

[image: postm]

```
    <?php
if (! isset($_POST['review'])) {
    responJson(['success' => false, 'messege' => "'review' harus diisi"]);
    exit;
}
if (! isset($_POST['rating'])) {
    responJson(['success' => false, 'messege' => "'rating' harus diisi"]);
    exit;
}
if (! isset($_POST['id_user'])) {
    responJson(['success' => false, 'messege' => "'id_user' harus diisi"]);
    exit;
}
if (! isset($_POST['id_movie'])) {
    responJson(['success' => false, 'messege' => "'id_movie' harus diisi"]);
    exit;
}

//bersihkan data
$review = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['review']);
$rating = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['rating']);
$user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['id_user']);
$movie_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['id_movie']);

//masukkan data ke db
$query = mysqli_query($connection, 'INSERT INTO user_review (review, rating, id_user, id_movie)
values ("'. $review .'", "'. $rating .'", "'. $user_id .'", "'. $movie_id .'")');
//cek berhasil atau tidak dimasukkan db
if ($query) {
    responJson(['success' => true, 'messege' => 'sukses memasukkan data']);
} else {
    responJson(['success' => false, 'messege' =>  mysqli_error($connection)]);
}
```

Comment: try to echo your query string and run it directly you will get exact error.

Comment: Not quite sure from the top of my head if MySQL allows it, but you seem to generate a query with double quotes around your strings `values("a","b","c","d")`. They should be single quotes.

Comment: I think it can be both @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: now it can insert but the value are not

Comment: I won't use concatenation to create an insert statement, potential security issue for SQL Injection. I am not sure if `'feedback')\nvalues` is the cause. try removing the line break. and change code to use query parameters instead of concatenation. you can check this tutorial https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-prepared-statements.php

Comment: actually it all works. the only thing that won't work because it not get the value from body that I put in postman

Comment: Try to do a print_r of the $_POST to see if you are getting any value

Comment: it's not getting any value because when I remove the first line of code it works but in database there is no value on it. only the column

Comment: it not getting any value when in print it @nacho

Comment: If I get the return message correctly, this question has nothing to do with mysqli or databases.

Comment: The php code is stopping in the first if, just see your error message **'messege' :"'review'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click raw and select json(application/json) from dropdown and  add following code in body in json format

```
{
  "review": "bagus",
  "rating": "3",
  "id_user": "2",
  "id_movie": "3"
}
```